# Help required to implement the below model using Bi-GRU

Tags: keras, rnn, autoencoder

[image]

[image]

As you can see in above images I need to model Bi-GRUs stacked as shown in table which takes input (N,1,64) and outputs (N,204). The input data is binary number stream and so is output data. Can anyone please help me get started?

Thank you.

Comment: In general, Bi-GRU refers to "Bidirectional GRU". The architecture you show here does not seem to be bidirectional, so "Stacked GRU" or "2-layer GRU" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense,BatchNormalization
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(800, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(1, 64)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(BatchNormalization())  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(800))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(204, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
```

I figured it out on my own.

Comment: This is a simple LSTM, not a bidirectional GRU. This model is not the one you're looking for

Comment: Right. I would put bidirectional clause in there.